# uninitialized constant Spreadsheet::Link - roo gem - xlsx file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, xlsx

When I open a file in xlsx format, using empact/roo gem, this line of code:

```
data = Roo::Spreadsheet.open("/Users/asd/Desktop/in_xlsx.xlsx", extensions: :xlsx)
```

or this line

```
data = Roo::Excelx.new("/Users/asd/Desktop/in_xlsx.xlsx")
```

works perfect! (at least this is what I think)

`data` is now a `Roo::Excelx` object with the columns and rows filled correctly.

But whenever I try to use a method like `data.first_row` or `data.cell(1,1)`, I get this

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Spreadsheet::Link
from /Users/asd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@ch/gems/roo-1.13.2/lib/roo/excelx.rb:379:in `set_cell_values'
```

Additional info:

- MacOS 10.9.1
- Rails 4.0.2
- Ruby 2.0.0-p353
- Roo (1.13.2)

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: In the roo document, it says `Excel.new(YOUR-FILE-PATH)` will work. http://roo.rubyforge.org/

Comment: It's a xlsx file, I'm not sure why you think this will work. Anyway, I 've tried but the results is : TypeError: asd.com/1394530457_in_xlsx.xlsx is not an Excel file

Comment: In the end, i used this gem instead - https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet . There was no way of solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> require 'rubygems'
>
> require 'roo'

For more information http://roo.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I said it returnes a Roo::Excelx object, would that happen if I don't require 'roo'?

Comment: It may happen so better require 'roo' and try to call .cell

Comment: That link is broken